# Sharing a page in Etsy will have the same currency

Tags: parameters, etsy

It seems no matter what I try, the currency of the Etsy shop/item is determined by the page after accessing it. So I can't share a page with a currency set by me and let the other person see that same currency.

I don't know if it is saved by a cookie, but its definitely not set by the URL params, as HTTP GET require (every GET request should have the same result)

Is it possible?